# want to cut data from vertical cells and paste them horizontally

Tags: excel, transpose

I have an excel data like below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjAZx.jpg)

1st image is actual data
&
2nd image is data required

want to cut data from vertical cells and paste them horizontally.

and I want to transpose it to like below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bezjx.jpg)

Can any one provide any solution to do this I have 100s of rows to transpose

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the data is in row A, and you want you output in row's B and C:

`=INDEX($A:$A;ROW(A1)*2-1)` in B1, and extend down.

`=INDEX($A:$A;ROW(A1)*2)` in C1, and extend down.

This is the result:

[image: Result]